# Redirecting with React history.push() does not reflect the input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-router

I'm building an APP with Firebase and react.

In that APP, when a user edits their information and presses the submit button, it redirects them to the user information page by history.push().

Both the user's information and the page redirection work well, but after redirecting the page, the user's information that was edited is not reflected, and the page displays the previous version of the user's information.

Here's my code.

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react"
import { Form, Button, Card, Alert } from "react-bootstrap"
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext"
import { Link, useHistory, Redirect, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import { db } from "../firebase"
import Dashboard from "../components/Dashboard"

export default function UpdateProfile() {
  const usernameRef = useRef()
  const emailRef = useRef()
  const passwordRef = useRef()
  const passwordConfirmRef = useRef()
  const { updateUser, currentUser, updatePassword } = useAuth()
  const [error, setError] = useState("")
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const history = useHistory()

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfirmRef.current.value) {
      return setError("Passwords do not match")
    }

    if (passwordRef.current.value) {
      updatePassword(passwordRef.current.value)
    }

    const uid = currentUser.uid
    db.collection('users').doc(uid).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      const data = snapshot.data() 
      try {
        setLoading(true)
        setError("")
        updateUser(usernameRef.current.value, emailRef.current.value, data)
        history.push('/dashboard')
      } catch {
        setError("Failed to update account")
      }
      setLoading(false)
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <Card.Body>
          <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Update Profile</h2>
          {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group id="username">
              <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="text"
                ref={usernameRef}
                required
                defaultValue={currentUser.username}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id="email">
              <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="email"
                ref={emailRef}
                required
                defaultValue={currentUser.email}
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id="password">
              <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="password"
                ref={passwordRef}
                placeholder="Leave blank to keep the same"
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id="password-confirm">
              <Form.Label>Password Confirmation</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                type="password"
                ref={passwordConfirmRef}
                placeholder="Leave blank to keep the same"
              />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button disabled={loading} className="w-100" type="submit">
              Update
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
        <Link to="/">Cancel</Link>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

And I use AuthContext to pass Firebase credentials to each component.
This is part of the AuthContext file.

```js
  function updateUser(username, email, data) {
    const uid = data.uid
    db.collection('users').doc(uid).set({
      email: email,
      username: username,
    }, {merge: true})
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async(user) => {
      if (user) {
        const uid = user.uid
        console.log(uid)
        await db.collection('users').doc(uid).get()
          .then(snapshot => {
            const data = snapshot.data()
            setCurrentUser(data)
            setLoading(false)
          })
      }
    })
    
    return unsubscribe
  }, [])
```

Do you know how to reflect the values I have entered on the edit screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since `updateUser` is an async function so you should use either `async await` or `.then` syntax in your `updateUser` function so that it calls the `history.push` after updating the user data

```
function updateUser(username, email, data) {
    const uid = data.uid
    return db.collection('users').doc(uid).set({
        email: email,
        username: username,
      }, {merge: true})
  }
```

```
     updateUser(usernameRef.current.value, emailRef.current.value, data)
       .then(() => {
           history.push('/dashboard');
       }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I tried using the `then()`, but instead of redirecting to `/dashboard`, I got "Failed to update account". The error message is what I wrote in the catch handling section, so it's likely that the `history.push()` didn't run and resulted in an error.
Is there any good solution?